# Multiple Animations to a Sprite

Tags: iphone

How to Add Multiple Animations to a Sprite, (i.e) one animation after another finished.
Also how to remove the old animation from the sprite.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

[Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/).